# Dropbox doesn't work on scientific linux

Tags: rhel, dropbox

Installed dropbox on scientific linux (command line only) several months ago and it has been working fine. I installed it for one user, and I control it using the CLI dropbox.py.

Recently I restarted it, and now all commands give the 'Dropbox isn't running!' error. 'dropbox start' gives the error:

```
Dropbox isn't running!
Dropbox is already running!
```

`ps -ef |grep dropbox` confirms that there is a process called dropbox in the .dropbox-dist folder running

I am running version 3.0.3 of dropbox

fiddling with the dropbox.py script tells me that the line that is causing the problems is

```
self.s.connect(os.path.expanduser(u'~/.dropbox/command_socket'))
```

I can't seem to read the command_socket file and `ls -l` says that its size is 0

Comment: Try renaming or moving ~/.dropbox somewhere else

Answer (score 0):

Check the post by avatar in

https://www.dropboxforum.com/hc/communities/public/questions/201559815-RHEL-6-6-Dropbox-lnx-x86-64-3-0-3-will-not-start-

Do:

```
rm ~/.dropbox-dist/dropbox-lnx.x86*/libxml2.so.2
```